# Passing values to an "unbounded" variable in wsdl using php soap client

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

My wsdl defines a method named paymentconfirmation and it has these set of parameters but the problem is one of them is an unbounded type. How to pass values to this variable?

```
<xs:complexType name="paymentConfirmation">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="msgType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="tranType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reqType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="dcId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="totalRecs" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="stan" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="paymentDate" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="terminalId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="terminalLocation" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="txnType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="kioskId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ns1:adviceRecord"/>//defines the unbounded variable
    </xs:sequence>
//definition of adviceRecord
<xs:element name="adviceRecord" type="tns:adviceRecord"/>
<xs:complexType name="adviceRecord">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address2" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="zipCode" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="contactNo" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="paymentMode" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="txnId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="consumerNo" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="consumerNoFlag" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceTypeId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="serviceTypeMnemName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="billNo" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="paidAmt" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="nric" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved2" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved3" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved4" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved5" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved6" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved7" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved8" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved9" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="reserved10" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

how to pass the values to that last unbound parameter. I could pass the values to the rest of the parameters. this is the error i receive:
rray ( [PaymentserviceServicePayment::paymentConfirmation] => SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Unmarshalling Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'adviceRecord' is not complete. One of '{customerName, address1, address2, zipCode, contactNo, paymentMode}' is expected.
I am using php soap client.

Comment: Are you using http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php SoapVar to create the complex type can you show code

Comment: i used wsdltophp converter and just calling the method by passing the parametes in an array.

Comment: $advicerecord=array("Tan Meng","test","address","6512244","988107251","A");$paymentserviceServicePayment->paymentConfirmation(new PaymentserviceStructPaymentConfirmation("0200","99","04","04","1","NULL","23/06/2008 15:25:25","NULL","NULL","E","NULL",$advicerecord))

Comment: @ShaunHare thank you. i got the response by using php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php

Comment: great glad it helped feel free to edit the question so others can benefit